# English language or English Language?

Tags: capitalization

In the following sentence, should language start with a capital letter?

> We can give children more opportunities if we teach them English
> **Language** at primary school

I know we must say "National Museum", because it is a specific museum. Similarly, I think it should be "English Language" as we do not talk about every language. Is it correct?

Comment: If you think of other subjects we teach children - history, science, art, etc - those are not caplitalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, language should not be capitalized. The word *English* in *English language* is a proper adjective, formed from the proper noun *England* and it is capitalized,but *language* is not a proper noun.

If there is a *National Museum* and that is its full proper name, then that should be capitalized.